# Gulp Not Found Even after Changing Global File Path

Tags: node.js, gulp, git-bash

I've done all of the recommendations found in other StackOverflow posts about this, but the issue still isn't resolved. I've run the prefix command without it fixing the issue, attempted to remove Gulp and re-install, and run npm install and npm update. Been working on this for hours and no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running Git Bash with the following folders:

```
$ npm root -g
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules

$ npm root --dev
C:\Users\HalvorSD\mofficialdev\node_modules

$ npm root -g gulp
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules
```

Under environment variables in Advanced System Properties, I have:

```
Variable name: NODE_PATH
Variable value: %AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

Comment: Could you please show the output of `npm root -g gulp` ?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: Thanks, and can you please show the error you're seeing?

Comment: It's bash: gulp: command not found

Comment: I think you're missing a link to system32 ... I think you should `ln -s` it manually... I use linux :/

Comment: So what would I enter in the command prompt to create the link for system32?

Comment: Also... you are running in a virtual environment if so... because windows doesn't have bash... it has cmd with an annoying backslash and with it's own env...

Comment: So you are saying that running the same commands in a normal command prompt or in node.js command prompt would somehow fix the issue?

Comment: I'd guess something like `ln \s c:\pathToGulp c:\sys32path\gulp`

Comment: Hmm, I will look into it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The two prompts have different environment variables... maybe you added the environment vars to the wrong prompt or installed it outside the virtual environment... have you tried restarting this git-shell ?

Comment: It's possible. Maybe I will try deleting the global installation files manually and re-installing Gulp

Comment: I'd have started with that.. you just wrote that you did.. or I misunderstood :)

Comment: I tried to using the command shell but was having issues. I might need to do it manually

Comment: Have you tried https://www.cygwin.com/ ?

Comment: Yeah, no luck manually deleting and re-installing files. What is cygwin?

Comment: linux shell for win32